# Testing log-in app and redirection in Cypress

Tags: cypress, e2e-testing

The app I'm trying to test has a separate log-in app, that redirects to my app.

I start the test at the log-in app (running on `localhost:4200`), fill the mock log-in, and the app should be redirected to my app (running on `localhost:4206`).

I tried to follow [this](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/web-security#External-Navigation) documentation segment, but I'm probably doing it wrong.

```js
describe('log-in', () => {
  it('show my app', () => {
    cy.visit('http://127.0.0.1:4200/login/my-app');
    cy.get('#mat-input-0').type('user{enter}'); // should log in and redirect

    cy.origin('http://127.0.0.1:4206', () => {
      cy.should('contain', 'Hello, World!');
      // ?
    });
  });
});
```

I think Cypress isn't allowing the redirection. The test page shows 'The connection has been reset' message, and the `origin` command (that expected the redirection) looks like this:

[image]

Can I be more explicit in telling Cypress I want to allow the redirection? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```js
cy.visit('http://localhost:4206');
cy.origin('http://localhost:4200', () => {
  cy.get('input:first').type('user{enter}');
});
cy.location('pathname').should('eq', '/');
cy.contains('Hello, World!');
```

Basically we should only use `visit` to define the main place where we'll be testing. `origin` will verify redirection and we can execute test code in that temporary location. Then, back out of the `origin` callback function, Cypress assumes we're testing at the `visit` location.